# JSON.stringify() returning null

Tags: javascript, .net

Why would `typeof(JSON.stringify(outputdata))` return a string in debug console, while I recieve null in backend(.NET 5)?

Backend part:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("createpost")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost([FromBody] Article article)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CONTENT: " + article.Content);
    
            return Json(article);
        }
```

`outputData` is my JSON

Article.cs model:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Following code is my POST request:

```
fetch('/createpost', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      Content : JSON.stringify(this.outputData)
    })
  });
```

`` Content : JSON.stringify(` ${this.outputData} `) `` returns undefined

Comment: Why do you believe the frontend code is the issue?

Comment: You are  stringifying it twice. Just do `body: JSON.stringify({ Content: this.outputData })`

Answer (score 0):

It is already stringified by the first `JSON.stringify`, the second one sees the stringified json as a string.

try:

```js
fetch('/createpost', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      Content : this.outputData
    })
  });
```

Comment: I still receive null with this

Comment: i think it should be fetch('/createpost', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      article : this.outputData
    })
  });

Comment: I want whole json as a string to avoid creating complicated model in backend